# Why does Fn+A keybinding not work in Zenbooks?

Tags: shortcut-keys, laptop, asus

By default, the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> combo doesn't work, so I wanted to map that keycode to a script.
I created a shortcut that maps to the keycode (`0xf8`) but it doesn't work. Additionally, my <kbd>o</kbd> key does not work. 
When I change the mapping to something else (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> for example), everything works as expected.

Experimenting with the second hardware. 
The first keybindings do not work with the graphic packages `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, nor `modesetting` after purging the intel package and rebooting. The problem may be GPU independent because the first hardware configuration is with NVidia, while the second is with Intel.

Ubuntu: 14.04, 16.04
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX32VD, Zenbook UX303UA
Linux kernel: 3.19.0-42, 4.4-4.7
GPU: NVidia Geforce GT 620M, Intel integrated
Graphic packages in 2nd hardware: `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, `modesetting`

Comment: Can you show us a piece of code how you map the keycode, please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the operating system can't "see" the Fn key being pressed. Fn keypresses are interpreted by the BIOS. I'm happy to be proven wrong, but I think this issue has come up before

Comment: @NickWeinberg Yes, I can prove that you are wrong. See the answer below. Pressing Fn+something else gives you different keybinding than just something else.

Answer (score 2):

The OP wants to express the function of the keybinding <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> i.e. Fig. 1 Print of the keybinding in the keyboard where it has the lamp -symbol with the word *auto*; please, comment if you know what is the name of this feature exactly

[image]

Below you can see that the keybinding combination returns zero bytes i.e. its function is connected nowhere. 
Options to solve the case

1. Use the graphic package `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` TODO Similar approach is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/816622/25388) in the thread *How to Enable Brightness Buttons in 16.04 of Zenbook?* but I am not sure about the precise method what to change.
2. Use `modesetting` i.e. purge the Intel graphic package, and find an alternative stable method.

### Experimenting the keycodes in UX303UA

Do `xev`, press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> where you see that there is a difference between the two keybindings in the system, but the action is not run

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0xe6, subw 0x0, time 112925284, (10,-18), root:(10,34),
    state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0xe6, subw 0x0, time 112925284, (10,-18), root:(10,34),
    state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

MappingNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0xe6, subw 0x0, time 112926726, (10,-18), root:(10,34),
    state 0x0, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0xe6, subw 0x0, time 112926790, (10,-18), root:(10,34),
    state 0x0, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Ubuntu: 16.04
Linux kernel: 4.4-4.7
GPU: Intel integrated
Graphic packages: xserver-xorg-video-intel, modesetting

Comment: Fn+A is meant to control the [Ambient Light Sensor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Zenbook_UX303#Ambient_Light_Sensor_.28ALS.29) (ALS). However, I've not yet enabled it on my UX303UA.