# How to Enable Brightness Buttons when acpi_osi of Grub not enough in 16.04 of Zenbook?

Tags: laptop, asus, media-buttons

**Situation**: to use <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> for decrease and increase of brightness, respectively, in Asus Zenbook UX303UA, when I can change brightness in System Preferences, and `acpi_osi=` is not sufficient in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` of `/etc/default/grub`.
**Related**: (See [Brightness hotkey doesn't work on laptop asus k501ux [Ubuntu 16.04.1]](https://askubuntu.com/q/804775/25388) and [Screen brightness keys not working (fn + f5/f6)](https://askubuntu.com/q/813304/25388)) where the latter is sufficient.
Ubuntu's docs says, but it is outdated and does not particularly include 16.04

> NOTE: As of BIOS update 214 "Support Windows8 brightness control" is
>   added. This means that the brightness buttons won't work in Ubuntu any
>   longer. Brightness workaround 2 in the Zenbook Prime wiki works fine
>   for changing brightness.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime#Keyboard) some Bash scripts about the setup but their bindings are false for the different system. 
Doing `xev`, pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd>, and studying the outputs which shows that the actions are doing nothing (`0 bytes` transmitted), showing UEFI firmware problem (Pilot6)

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0xb5, subw 0x0, time 16483030, (-1385,943), root:(303,995),
    state 0x0, keycode 71 (keysym 0xffc2, F5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0xb5, subw 0x0, time 16483120, (-1385,943), root:(303,995),
    state 0x0, keycode 71 (keysym 0xffc2, F5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0xb5, subw 0x0, time 16483312, (-1385,943), root:(303,995),
    state 0x0, keycode 72 (keysym 0xffc3, F6), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0xb5, subw 0x0, time 16483387, (-1385,943), root:(303,995),
    state 0x0, keycode 72 (keysym 0xffc3, F6), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

### Unsuccessful output

Do

1. Add the option `acpi_osi` without value in your `/etc/default/grub` file like this

   ```
   # guillaume-desclaux https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243162
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
   ```
2. Run `update-grub`
3. Restart

**Output**: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> does not work as expected: shows the sign of changes in brightness at the top-right corner but not actually affect the brightness at all.

- Fig. 1 Brightness set to minimum
- Fig. 2 Brightness increased without a change in the brightness
- Fig. 3 Brightness changes now accordingly in System Preferences

[image: fig 1]
[image: fig 2]
[image: fig 3]

### Bios upgrade?

I extended this issue in a new thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307443/16920).
I did not need to upgrade finally the bios because it was the latest (2 month old laptop 4th September 2016).

- **Hardware**: Asus Zenbook UX303UA R4028T, UX305
- **OS**: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit, 14.04
- **Documentation**: Ubuntu's [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook) about Asus Zenbook, Asus Zenbook Prime [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime) not apparently relevant
- **Related**: [How can I change brightness on Zenbook UX305 with media-buttons?](https://askubuntu.com/q/696239/25388)
- **Differential solution**: ALS sensor with non-apt-get software etc [here](https://github.com/Perlover/Asus-Zenbook-Ambient-Light-Sensor-Controller/tree/asus-ux305)

Comment: Did you try the `acpi_osi=` solution?

Comment: Can you change brightness from System Settings? `acpi_osi=` works for me in 16.04.

Comment: You need to see if these keys generate events.

Comment: You need to check if pressing these keys generate evens. You can check by `xev`.

Comment: This is a problem related to the UEFi firmware. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @Pilot6 Please, see the body for the unsuccessful attempt for the fix and consideration about the BIOS update.

Comment: So the buttons started working. You need to add a conf. See http://askubuntu.com/a/536618/167850

Comment: @Pilot6 Great! It works now. Thank you! I created a wiki about it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add the option `acpi_osi` without value in the parameter `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` of your `/etc/default/grub` file, like in the body

   ```
   # guillaume-desclaux https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243162
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
   ```
2. Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and add the following there

   ```
   # http://askubuntu.com/a/536618/25388
   Section "Device"
           Identifier "card0"
           Driver "intel"
           Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
           BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
   ```
3. Run `sudo update-grub`.

Output: brightness control works as expected now.

Comment: That is what I did in my Asus laptop. I thought that you tried that already. There were a lot of questions about that. There are 2 issues: 1. The buttons do not generate events. It can be fixed by `acpi_osi=`. 2. They control a wrong interface. That is fixed by the conf file.

Comment: This solved the issue on my X550LA. Cheers!