# tried to fix a bug in X11 and now black screen at boot

Tags: 16.04, xorg, asus

I had an issue with flickering on chrome and I saw what seemed to be a fix on the following thread: [Why is Display flickering in Chrome/Chromium of Zenbook UX303UA with Google Plus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816631/why-is-display-flickering-in-chrome-chromium-of-zenbook-ux303ua-with-google-plus)

so I did the following:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Paste this:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option "TearFree" "true"
   Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
Save (CTRL + O) and reboot."
```

Except than on reboot, after I enter my encryption password, I have a black screen. I'am on 16.04 and my computer is an Asus UX305F. I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndroidDev I don't think it should be duped to that as it's a clear and specific question - the real problem is the flickering anyway

Comment: @Zanna - I completely agree with you. I think that canonical question is way over-used. However, I felt that it was going to be duped to that anyway, so...

Comment: looks like OP of question you linked to didn't use that method to fix their problem.

Comment: If you really added this line `Save (CTRL + O) and reboot."` to the file, then remove it. It was not supposed to be added there.