# Intel uhd 620 doesn't support opengl 4, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl

I recently bought a Dell Inspiron 15" 5570, the version with Intel i5 8250u and just the iGPU intel UHD 620.
After installing Ubuntu i had some screen flickering and I managed it by using the [Joakim's workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816631/why-is-display-flickering-in-chrome-chromium-of-zenbook-ux303ua-with-google-plus?rq=1) but now I'm facing another problem which I couldn't figure out.
I need OpenGL 4, that the integrated gpu support but I don't know how to "enable" it.
That's the `glxinfo | grep -i opengl` output:

```
glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

And this is another glxinfo part which might be useful:

```
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)  (0x5917)
    Version: 18.2.0
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
```

And this is the output error when I try to start the program which needs opengl 4:

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  40
  Current serial number in output stream:  39
```

I've heard about such an alpha boot option to enable the alpha driver for my CPU but just miss that, thanks in advance for the help.

--UPDATE--
I actually "managed" the error, I tried other progams which needs openGL 4 funcionality, openGL 4.5 context, and works without problems but when I want to use this "legacy" OpenGL program which needs a 4.5 context

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#  include <GL/glew.h>
#  include <GL/freeglut.h>
#  include <OpenGL/glext.h>
#else
#  include <GL/glew.h>
#  include <GL/freeglut.h>
#  include <GL/glext.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
#endif

#define PI 3.14159265358979324

using namespace std;

// Globals.
static float R = 40.0; // Radius of circle.
static float X = 50.0; // X-coordinate of center of circle.
static float Y = 50.0; // Y-coordinate of center of circle.
static int numVertices = 10; // Number of vertices on circle.

// Drawing routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
   float t = 0; // Angle parameter.

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   // Draw a line loop with vertices at equal angles apart on a circle
   // with center at (X, Y) and radius R, The vertices are colored randomly.
   /* Funzione seno esercizio pag56 2.27
   glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
      for(float i = -PI; i <= PI; i+=PI/20.0)
      {
     glColor3f((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX, (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX, (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX);
     glVertex3f(i, sin(i), 0.0);
     //cout<<"x="<<i<<";y="<<sin(i);
     //t += 2 * PI / numVertices;
      }
   glEnd();*/
   //Ellisse esercizio pag56 2.28
   //x = X + A*cos(t), y = Y + B*sin(t), z=0,  0<=t<=2PI
   glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
      for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
   {
     glColor3f((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX, (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX, (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX);
     glVertex3f((R+10)*cos(t), (R-10)*sin(t), 0.0);
     //cout<<"x="<<i<<";y="<<sin(i);
     t += 2 * PI / numVertices;
   }
   glEnd();

   glFlush();
}

// Initialization routine.
void setup(void)
{
   glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

// OpenGL window reshape routine.
void resize(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(-50, 50, -50, 50, -1.0, 1.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}

// Keyboard input processing routine.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch(key)
   {
      case 27:
     exit(0);
     break;
      case '+':
     numVertices++;
     glutPostRedisplay();
     break;
      case '-':
     if (numVertices > 3) numVertices--;
     glutPostRedisplay();
     break;
      default:
     break;
   }
}

// Routine to output interaction instructions to the C++ window.
void printInteraction(void)
{
   cout << "Interaction:" << endl;
   cout << "Press +/- to increase/decrease the number of vertices on the circle." << endl;
}

// Main routine.
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printInteraction();
   glutInit(&argc, argv);

   glutInitContextVersion(4,5);
   glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);

   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
   glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow("circle.cpp");
   glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
   glutReshapeFunc(resize);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);

   glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
   glewInit();

   setup();

   glutMainLoop();
}
```

Gives the error:

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  40
```

But I can actually use it by starting it as follows:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5 ./circle
```

I don't know why maybe it is a bug, because when I try to compile the other programs, which works without MESA.. prefix, with:
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 6);
Instead of:
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 5);
It gives the same error of GLXBadFBConfig
So there aren't any OpenGL wrong context settings mitigation in the program itself.