# Can't get display and soundcard work correctly

Tags: sound, kernel, intel, gpu-driver

With 4.15 kernel, the display was working correctly, but my sound card Realtek audio wasn't working. That's why I changed kernel version to 4.19 (this is the first version which works with it) but the display went wrong.

I've tried [Why is Display flickering in Chrome/Chromium of Zenbook UX303UA with Google Plus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816631/) and [After most recent kernel update (4.15.0-44-generic) my tablet freezes whenever plugged into docking station](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113743) to fix it but it didn't work either.

I've tried 5.0 kernel too, but it is just worst.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? Have you compiled the kernel or installed using PPA?

Answer (score 0):

I used UKUU to change kernel versions - I use 18.04

Comment: @kulfy: Self-answer!  VTC Q and leave A intact if you really want to!  **;-)**